# Dynamically extract type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, mapped-types

I am trying to dynamically map one type to another based on certain flags, which might result in optional fields.

```
type Constraint = {
  required: boolean,
  callback: () => any,
}

type Schema = Record<string, Constraint>;

const mySchema: Schema = {
  bar: {
    required: true,
    callback: () => 1
  },
  foo: {
    required: false,
    callback: () => true
  }
}

type MapSchemaToOutput<T extends Schema> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K]['required'] extends true ? K : never]: ReturnType<T[K]['callback']>
} & {
  [K in keyof T as T[K]['required'] extends false ? K : never]?: ReturnType<T[K]['callback']>
}

type Output = MapSchemaToOutput<typeof mySchema>;
```

The end goal is to have Output equal:

```
{
  bar: number,
  foo?: boolean
}
```

I know I can do the mapping by hand, interested to know if this can be done dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach works as-is, with one change.

The issue is that the `: Schema` annotation is "throwing away type information":

```
const mySchema: Schema = {
   //...
};
```

With that annotation, TS only remembers that `mySchema` is `Record<string, Constraint>`, *not any of the specific structure of the object*.

---

One fix is `as const`:

```
const mySchema = {
    //...
} as const;
```

This preserves the literal types within the object.  However, there's no longer any constraints on the contents of `mySchema`, and any errors defining `mySchema` would have to be caught by the usage, rather than at definition-time.

---

A better fix is to use a helper function to introduce a constraint, without annotating the type directly:

```
function buildSchema<T extends Schema>(schema: T) { return schema; }

const mySchema = buildSchema({
   //...
});
```

Due to the `<T extends Schema>` constraint, TS will raise an error, as before, if the schema object doesn't match the specified type.

But unlike annotating the object's type, this type returned by this function is unchanged from the literal object which is passed to the function: so no type information is lost.

[With this change, the rest of the types work as expected](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1):

Your `MapSchemaToOutput` type is actually correct given the appropriate `T` type.  However it has some limitations when we apply it to `typeof mySchema`.

#### Record

`Schema` is a `Record` which means by definition that its keys are every `string`.  We lose the ability to see the specific keys which are actually present.

Your map type is ok because of `extends`.  But we don't want to apply the type `Schema` to the variable `mySchema`.  We need to get a more specific type for it.

#### Boolean Types

The type for the `boolean` values `true` and `false` will generally be inferred as `boolean` instead of their literal values.  If the type of `T[K]['required']` is `boolean` then that doesn't extend `true` or `false` so it won't meet either condition of the map.

I recommend removing the `extends` check for the optional property keys such that all properties will be included as optional by default.  Including required values in both places is not an issue because they are joined with `&` so it must be present in order to match both conditions.

### `as const` & `readonly`

In order to get the literal `boolean` values of `mySchema` we need to use `as const`.  This infers all values as literals.  It also makes the type `readonly` and the mapped output will become `readonly` as well.  We can remove the `readonly` by adding [`-readonly`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24509) to the keys in the `MapSchemaToOutput` type.

Putting that all together, we get:

```
type MapSchemaToOutput<T extends Schema> = {
 -readonly[K in keyof T as T[K]['required'] extends true ? K : never]: ReturnType<T[K]['callback']>
} & {
 -readonly[K in keyof T]?: ReturnType<T[K]['callback']>
}
```

```
type Output = MapSchemaToOutput<typeof mySchema>;
```

resolves to:

```
type Output = {
    bar: number;
} & {
    bar?: number | undefined;
    foo?: boolean | undefined;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/N9AJjN)

Comment: Awesome and detailed answer, thanks! Went with @Retsam's answer as the helper function looked slighlty more elegant.